# How use in Magento2 inline translations with chosen locale in code? How select locale for inline translations in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, localisation, inline-translations

We need to have ability in code use inline translations with translated strings from csv files with selected locale, which is different from store. For example, user select english language in frontend, but we want to create PDF or rend email with de_DE translations. 
We want to get something like this (not correct this code)

```
> setLocale('de_DE');
> __('Good morning');
```

> `// Guten Morgen`

thanks

Comment: I have setUp by default, for example, English. Plus shop has many languages in Frontend for clients. And we have all translations in csv files in correct folders. everything work good. BUT, i want select directly in code to what language will translate strings, despite default locale in Backend and selected language for shop by Client.

Answer (score 0):

**I have found the solution!!!!** I have tried a lot of code and recommendations. But for me one way to solve my problem is next: 
So in Magento\Framework\App\Language\Dictionary class exist

```
function getDictionary($locale)
```

what returns array from csv files for selected locale. then I just get value from array by key - default string in base language - English.